# Inserting second disk during installation of OS in VMware

Tags: vmware-player, redhat-enterprise-linux

Hello I'm installing [Red Hat 9](http://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/9/en/iso/i386/)(version from 2009). Everything was good until the installation program asked for the second disk, now I don't know how to add the second cd and continue the installation. I'm using VMware Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on `Player -> Removable Devices -> CD/DVD -> Settings`, Browse for the 2nd disk, click Ok, then proceed with the installation in the player.

Comment: Thank you, it was in front my eyes most of the time. I will give you best answer when I can.